# Document thumbnails generated from preview content

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, document, thumbnails

I'm creating a grid of cells that represent downloaded files of various types (PDF, Images, Videos, HTML, .pages, .numbers, Word, etc.) in an ios application and am looking for a way to preemptively create preview thumbnails for these documents to show in the cells.  I'm currently using the UIDocumentInteractionController for previewing these documents after the user selects one and was hoping that the icons array would return the preview images.  Unfortunately, it only returns a generic icon.

I see that Pages and Numbers do this, but they own the documents and the format.  I was hoping that the Quicklook framework would provide a solution, but I haven't yet found it.  Has anybody else found a way to easily generate these thumbnails?

I'd prefer to use an actual UIImage and not a UIWebView as others have suggested.  That solution seems to be a hack and I have to believe there's a better solution out there.

My next option is to generate a preview after they open the document by essentially capturing the view as an image, but that still seems hackish.

Anybody have any thoughts or clearer options?

Thanks,

Comment: I also want to implement this but not finding the solution other then uiwebview

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My solution:
I never found a complete solution this particular problem, but I was able to handle PDF's fairly efficiently.  I honestly don't remember if I wrote this or found an example.  If it's your code that was posted somewhere else, thanks!  The end result here is docImage is either null, or contains the first page of the PDF as an image.  When loading my table rows, I set the image preview to a default image and then run this code on a background thread using blocks.  Once complete, I simply animate the preview back into the cell.

```
NSURL *pdfFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:localFilePath];
CGPDFDocumentRef pdfDoc = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL((__bridge CFURLRef) pdfFileURL);
NSUInteger numPages = CGPDFDocumentGetNumberOfPages(pdfDoc);

if(numPages > 0) {
    docImage = [UIImage imageFromPDFDocumentRef:pdfDoc];
}
CGPDFDocumentRelease(pdfDoc);
```

UIImage Category:

```
@implementation UIImage (CGPDFDocument)

+(UIImage *)imageFromPDFDocumentRef:(CGPDFDocumentRef)documentRef {
    return [self imageFromPDFDocumentRef:documentRef page:1];
} 
+(UIImage *)imageFromPDFDocumentRef:(CGPDFDocumentRef)documentRef page:(NSUInteger)page {
    CGPDFPageRef pageRef = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(documentRef, page);
    CGRect pageRect = CGPDFPageGetBoxRect(pageRef, kCGPDFCropBox);

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(pageRect.size);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, CGRectGetMinX(pageRect),CGRectGetMaxY(pageRect));
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1, -1);  
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, -(pageRect.origin.x), -(pageRect.origin.y));
    CGContextDrawPDFPage(context, pageRef);

    UIImage *finalImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return finalImage;    
}
@end
```